# Real Analysis - Relation between closed graph and continuity of domain

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, closed-graph

This is a practice question we were given in class:

We are given that a mapping *f*: $R_1$ -> $R_1$ is continuous. Prove *H* ={$(x, f(x)) | x$ $\in$ $R_1$} is closed. Part (II) asks whether the converse is true.

Attempt at a solution:

(Part I): Let u $\in$ $R_1$ be arbitrary. Suppose {$u_k$} is a sequence that converges to u. By the continuity of *f*, we know that {$f(u_k)$} converges to $f(u)$. The by the Componentwise Convergence Theorem, we know ({$u_k$},{$f(u_k)$}) converges to $H(u)$=$(u,f(u))$. Since $H(u)$ is contained in $H$, this proves the graph of $H$ is closed.

First of all, is this proof correct? Also for the converse, I'm not really sure what the answer is (I think it's True/False, with no proof necessary). I know the idea is that given the closed graph $H$, $f: R_1 -> R_1$ is continuous. So I started with:

$H$ is closed. So whenever ({$u_k$},{$f(u_k)$}) converges to ($u, f(u))$, $(u,f(u))$ is in $H$. What does this imply about the continuity of $f$? Because if {$f(u_k)$} *doesn't* converge to $f(u)$, this doesn't invalidate the condition. Where would I go from here, or is a different approach necessary?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof for the first part seems fine.

Your idea for the converse is wrong.  A helpful true statement is that a function on a compact set is continuous if and only if its graph is **compact**.

For a counterexample, consider the function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1/x & x\neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
I claim that this discontinuous function has a closed graph.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely forgot about compactness when I was doing this. Thanks!